# Correlated MySQL subquery to Postgre

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

MySQL support Correlated Subqueries and also working properly to fecth records from my db ...but i need same query to run on AWS Redshift to bring same records but it gives error of `This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported yet`

**MYSQL Query**

```
SELECT IFNULL((SELECT IF (c.c_id,'',0) FROM customer c WHERE c.c_id = o.c_id AND DATE (c.date) >= DATE ('2020-01-24') AND DATE (c.date) <= DATE ('2020-02-22')),'BCK') AS cstatus,
   IF (o.os_id = 0,'Missing','Place') AS 'os',
   IFNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT o.c_id),0) AS 'customers',
   IFNULL(COUNT(o.o_id),0) AS 'orders',
   IFNULL(SUM(o.total),0) AS 'cell'
FROM order o
WHERE 1
AND   DATE (o.date) >= DATE ('2020-01-24')
AND   DATE (o.date) <= DATE ('2020-02-22')
GROUP BY cstatus,
     ostatus
ORDER BY cstatus,
     ostatus DESC
```

**Postgresql Query**

```
SELECT COALESCE((SELECT CASE WHEN c.c_id THEN NULL ELSE 0 END FROM customer c WHERE c.c_id = o.c_id AND DATE (c.date) >= DATE ('2020-01-24') AND DATE (c.date) <= DATE ('2020-02-22')),'BCK') AS cstatus,
   CASE WHEN o.os_id = 0 THEN 'Missing' ELSE 'Place' END AS ostatus,
   COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT o.c_id),0) AS customers,
   COALESCE(COUNT(o.o_id),0) AS orders,
   COALESCE(SUM(o.total),0) AS cell
FROM order o
WHERE 1
AND   DATE (o.date) >= DATE ('2020-01-24')
AND   DATE (o.date) <= DATE ('2020-02-22')
GROUP BY cstatus,
     ostatus
ORDER BY cstatus,
     ostatus DESC
```

This `postgre` query gives me `2` errors. `1- at 'BCK'` , `2- correlated subquery error`. (For `'BCK'` if i put integer it works, but i need string)

expected result will be like in attached image.

[image]

How can i handle this issue in AWS Redshift

Comment: You should complete your question by including sample data.

Comment: DAta is simple... order_id, Order_status, customer_id, count(orders) and total_sale ...all are integer data types.

Comment: Your comment is not helping your question.  We would like to understand what the input data looks like and also what the output looks like.

Comment: do a standard left join between order and customer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code would be much easier to follow with explanations on what it is trying to do.  The code looks suspicious, simply because it is a scalar subquery, but there is no guarantee that it never returns more than one row (say by using `LIMIT` or aggregation).

But, it appears to, suggesting that there is at most one customer per order.  With that assumption, you can replace the logic with some sort of `JOIN` without affecting the calculations:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN c.c_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'BCK' END) AS cstatus,
       (CASE WHEN o.os_id = 0 THEN 'Missing' ELSE 'Place' END) AS os,
       COUNT(DISTINCT o.c_id) AS customers,
       COUNT(o.o_id) AS orders,
       COALESCE(SUM(o.total), 0) AS cell
FROM order o LEFT JOIN
     customer c
     ON c.c_id = o.c_id AND
        c.date >= DATE('2020-01-24') AND
        c.date < DATE ('2020-02-23')
WHERE o.date >= DATE('2020-01-24') AND
      o.date < DATE('2020-02-23')
GROUP BY cstatus, ostatus
ORDER BY cstatus, ostatus DESC;
```

Note other changes to the query:

- The date comparisons work for both times and dates by using `<` for the second comparison.  This can be important for optimization and partition pruning (depending on the database).
- `COUNT()` and `COUNT(DISTINCT)` never return `NULL` values, so replacing `NULL`s with `0` is just wasted code.
- Use single quotes only for string and date constants.  Do not use them -- in any database -- for column aliases.